# How to make different webpages use one CSS file?

Tags: html, css, cpanel

I'm new to coding and understanding the cPanel File Manager.

I have uploaded my HTML webpages into folders and haven't been able to figure out how to make all of them use one CSS file. I've managed to make my pages all look as I want by uploading the CSS file into each webpage folder, but when I want to change one thing about the CSS, it gets really tiring to go through each individual one.

I'd imagine there's an easier way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What actual issue are you having? You can just point each one to the same CSS file

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/file.css">`

Comment: I tried to point each page to the same CSS file in the public_html. I named my sheet "main css.css," and each of my page's CSS reference line has <link href="main css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> at the top. But it's not getting used and only works when each page's folder has its own CSS file in it.

Comment: I'd rename that to `main.css`. If it's in the root folder, all you need is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your hierarchy looks like this:

```
index.html
other.html
more.html
styles.css
```

just put  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">` in the `<head>` of each page.

---

If instead, your hierarchy looks like this:

```
index.html
other.html
more.html
styles
    -styles.css
```

you can instead use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">` and so on

Comment: My hierarchy looks a bit different. I have each page into a different folder, that way I can name each of them index.html, that way their URL doesn't have .html at the end of them.

Comment: @Kludge reference them like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/styles.css">` or `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css">`. Also, there's much better ways to hide the `.html` extension than that hack.

Comment: What is the best way to hide the .html extension?

Comment: Ask another question if thats what you want, I believe I've answered the question you did ask though, right?

Comment: I tried putting `href="../styles/styles.css` (and `href="../styles/main css.css` since main css.ss is the name of my CSS file), but it still didn't work. I assume I'm supposed to redirect things in between or before the slashes, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @Kludge it would be `href="../main.css"` or `href="../styles/main.css"` if it is in a folder where `styles` is the name of the folder. `..` means to go back a directory. In your comment `href="../styles/main css.css` is not a valid path as you said `main css.css` and not `main.css`

Comment: main css.css is not in a folder, it's just there once I open public_html. Just putting `href="../main css.css"` worked! Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: Why is there a space in the middle of your file name? You should change that immediately. @Kludge

Comment: I didn't think there was anything wrong with it, but I can change it. In what case would a filename space affect anything?

Comment: @Kludge Actually I suppose on modern day computers it isnt really an issue anymore, but is still considred bad practice. The main caveat is that any time you refer to your path, you have to put it in quotes.

Comment: @kludge comments are not a chat room. If you have a different question ask it on a separate post to make it potentially helpful to others.